# change view router-oulet into side bar

Tags: angular, syncfusion

Hi i want know why I can´t acces to a child route.

I have a sidebar but into side bar I want display a list and if i want add a item or edit change view into side bar list to form, form to list

this is my appcomponent

```
<app-sidebar3></app-sidebar3>

app module 


<div id="root-content" (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
     class="e-main-content" style="font-size: 16px;  transform: translateX(0px); margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">

  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ApiAuthorizationModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    //Registering EJ2 grid module syncfusion
    SidebarModule,
    ToolbarModule,
    ListViewModule,
    DropDownButtonModule,
    CircularGaugeModule,

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    SideBar3Component,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(router: Router) { }
}
```

my app routing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, },
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports:
    [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
      {
        enableTracing: false // <-- debugging purposes only
        //preloadingStrategy: SelectivePreloadingStrategyService,
      }
    )
    ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is my side bar

```
<ejs-sidebar id="sidebar3" #sidebar3 [target]='target' [position]='position' [height]="innerHeight" [width]='width' [type]='type' [closeOnDocumentClick]='closeOnDocumentClick' [enableGestures]="false" (created)="created($event)">
    <div>
      <button ejs-button id="close-btn-sidebar3" class="e-btn close-btn float-left" (click)="sideBar3Hide()">
        <span id="innerclose" class="e-icons close-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="title3-sidebar3">SITIOS</div>


    <nav>
      <a routerLink="./sitioslist" routerLinkActive="active">SitiosList</a>
      <a routerLink="./sitiosform" routerLinkActive="active">SitiosForm</a>



    </nav>
    <router-outlet name="sidebar3outlet" #sidebar3outlet></router-outlet>
  </ejs-sidebar>
```

this is my sidebar3module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SideBar3RoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    SideBar3Component,
    SitiosListComponent,
    SitiosFormComponent,
  ]
})
export class SideBar3Module { }
```

my side bar routing

```
const sidebar3Routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SitiosListComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar3outlet',
    children: [
       {
        path: 'sitiosform',
        component: SitiosFormComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(sidebar3Routes),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SideBar3RoutingModule { }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhuSN.png)

Answer (score 0):

To navigate using router, you need to declare the routes in app-routing.module .ts files. We have prepared a similar sample for your requirement.

In this sample, we have rendered the sidebar in the main-page. Refer the below screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlvjg.png)

When click the Go to Sidebar3 page, it navigate to sidebar3 component and open the right sidebar.

```
const routes: Routes = [ { 
  path: '', 
  component: Sidebar1Component, 
  
}, 
{ 
  // When you click the sidebar3 and then it naviagte to sidebar3 component. 
  path: 'sidebar3', 
  component: Sidebar3Component, 
  // List and form component is the child component of sidebar3 component. 
  children: [ 
    { 
      // When you click go to list, it navigate to list component page. 
      path: 'list', 
      component: ListComponent 
    }, { 
       // When you click go to form, it navigate to form component page. 
      path: 'form', 
      component: FormComponent 
    } 
  ] 
}];
```

When you click the Go to Form page inside the right sidebar, it navigate to form component page. Refer the below code snippet.

```
<div class="value"> 
        <!-- navigate to form page when click the form tag --> 
        <a [routerLink]="['/sidebar3', 'form']">Go to Form</a> 
        </div> 
        <div class="value"> 
            <!-- navigate to list page iehen click the list value --> 
            <a [routerLink]="['/sidebar3', 'list']">Go to List</a> 
      </div>
```

Refer the sample link below.
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/my-app-2018000553.zip

Please let us know, if you need any further assistance.

Regards,
Sowmiya.P